# Laravel get the value of dynamic radio button in jquery created with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a form in my view where I have populated some dynamic radio buttons using data from the database. Code looks like this-

```
<div class="row">
@foreach($status as $s)
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="status" name="status" value="{{$s->id}}" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span id="status-name" class="custom-control-description">
                {{$s->specification}}
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div
```

and in HTML-

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input id="status" name="status" value="1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span id="status-name" class="custom-control-description">Yes</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Yes
            
        
    
    
        
           
           
           
               Yes

Now I want to send it to controller through ajax.I have tried this-

```
var status = document.getElementsByName('status').value;
if(status) {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/getpriceajax'+'/'+status,
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       success:function(data) {
           $('#calculated_price').val(data[0]);
           document.getElementById("price-show").innerHTML = "Product price is "+ data[0]+"and "+data[1];           
           $(".phone-value-details").slideDown(700);
           return false;
       }
   });
}else{

}
```

But it is always sending the value of the first radio button whether it is selected it or not. I have realized that it is happening because two radio buttons have the same name and by default, jquery is taking the first one. So, I think of renaming them dynamically. like-

```
name="status_{{$s->id}}"
```

But I don't know how to access this dynamic name or id in Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the name of the `status` input. But you need to change id  attributes to make them [unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) on the whole document. Or just do not use them if they are not needed in client-side scripts or CSS.

To get the value of the `status` use the following code:

```
var status = $('input[name="status"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can use**

```
    $('input[name="status"]').each(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            // $.ajax code with $(this).val()
        }
    });
```